# Union on Table Per Class Hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a requirement. Currently there is a search page which has List Box  with Values (Example Data) 1) Employee and 2) Sport Person.
Object Hierarchy (Hibernate Bean)
        Person is the actual Object which has two different class 
               1) Employee and 
               2) Sports Person based 
         Discriminator Column
         Person_Type (Discriminator Column).

On a search page , if user selects any of the list box, will result the data from that sub class.

Now requirement is to show both sub class result together and  it is done by adding one more value in the list box as "Employee + Sports Person".

Problem's
  1) Both sub class have different structure
  2) There are other criteria which are compared with different attributes.

How can I union the two sub classes.
Please help me to resolve. 
Please Note : I am trying not use Query Based Union. I am think in terms of OOPS

Comment: I don't quite get your problem: you have a list that contains employees and sports persons and need to sort that list based on different criteria?

Comment: @Thomas, I think I mixed UI and Hibernate Object Hierarchy. List Box is an UI Element which has Two Values. Based on the selection DAO is run on Sub Class. Value in the List Box is the Person_Type which is a Discriminator Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading both types of persons should not be a problem. If your query can access common attributes you can do `FROM Person p WHERE <whatever_person_criteria_you_have>`.

If your query need to use specific attributes of `Employee` and `SportsPerson` then you could execute 2 queries and put the result into a single `List<Person>`.

Sorting/displaying that list depends on what data needs to be displayed or compared. In case you have to compare different data, you could always use a `Comparator<Person>` which checks the actual class of the objects and maybe a wrapper which does the same to access the correct properties for display.

Comment: I executed two Quires to the get the result as criteria are specific to Sub Class. But my boss really asking me in one hit... or use Native Query(Which I am not ok with that)

Comment: @Kumar I'd ask your boss _why_ you have to use two queries. I'd prefer using two simple queries over a single more complex one, especially if you'd have to fall back to native sql (I'm also not ok with that ;) ). If a single query gets too complex multiple queries to get the same result might even yield better performance in addition to being easier to maintain.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I just told him, but you know boss is always right :-). But in reality your option is correct.

Comment: Added to above point, I think Hibernate have to think of providing the Union. Hope this is [https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-8666] Issue will be fixed soon

Comment: @Kumar it seems like it has been fixed 3 years ago :)

Comment: Sorry wrong link. Here is correct on [https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050]